# Error Calling a Java Method From Native C++ Using JNI (ACCESS_VIOLATION error)

Tags: java, c++, methods, java-native-interface

I got a problem : I try to call a java method that's supposed to print something in the console. It is called from a C++ native dll using JNI.
The problem is that it won't work and I get that error :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6c5f5253, pid=4472, tid=4956
#
# JRE version: 6.0_29-b11
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.4-b02 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x6c5f5253
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\location\MyApp\hs_err_pid4472.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Here is the C++ code I use to call a simple java method that will print a row in console :

```
jclass jTablObjClass = env->FindClass("MainFrame/Jni/TablesObjects");           // get jclass   
jmethodID printMethId = env->GetMethodID(jTablObjClass, "print", "()V");        // get jmethod
env->CallVoidMethod(jTablObjClass, printMethId);                                // call jmethod
```

Please, help ! ^^

Comment: Add return value checks to find out precise place of failure. Check all return values if they are not null.

Comment: In fact, the source of the crash is the call of the void java method `env->CallVoidMethod(jTablObjClass, printMethId);` But there's actually no reason for it to crash so ...

Comment: `jTablObjClass` and `printMethId` are not null?

Comment: How could I check that plz ? Is there a function I should use ?

Comment: `if(jTablObjClass  == NULL) {report an error and do something}`

Comment: CallVoidMethod's first parameter should be the object instance (having a print method).

Comment: I tried that `if(jTablObjClass == NULL) printf("empty tableObj"); else printf("not empty tableObj");` And I does tell me that the file isn't null... (And also for the printMethod...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, just realized. You are calling `CallVoidMethod` but the first argument is a class. If the method is a static, you should use `GetStaticMethodID` and `CallStaticVoidMethod`, if the method is not static, you should give an object instance, not a class.

Comment: Thank you very much ! You are great! I tried to set my java method "static" and in my native c++ code, I call the `GetStaticMethodID` and then the `CallStaticVoidMethod` and it actually did work out ! ^^ So thank you so much !